# Why is the `if else` not working?

Tags: theme-development, themes, headers, conditional-content

I have this on my `header.php`.

It checks whether the page is on homepage/frontpage, is on category/children of/has the category of "gamenews", or is on category/children of/has the category of "hobbynews".

Basically, if it's on homepage/frontpage, it outputs nothing.

On the other hand, if it's on gamenews, it outputs something. If it's on hobbynews, it outputs another thing. You could see in details below. I'm using a custom function there (`is_category_or_sub`).

```
        <?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>

        <?php } elseif ( is_category_or_sub('gamenews') || has_category('gamenews') ) { ?>
        <ul id="sections">
            <?php $category = get_category_by_slug( 'gamenews' );
            wp_list_categories(array(
                  'child_of' => $category->term_id,
                  'title_li' => '',
                  'hide_empty' => 0,
                  'orderby' => 'count',
                  'walker' => new WPSE67791_Walker_Category
               )); ?>
        </ul><!-- #sections -->

        <?php } elseif ( is_category_or_sub('hobbynews') || has_category('hobbynews') ) { ?>
        <ul id="sections">
            <?php $category = get_category_by_slug( 'hobbynews' );
            wp_list_categories(array(
                  'child_of' => $category->term_id,
                  'title_li' => '',
                  'hide_empty' => 0,
                  'orderby' => 'count',
                  'walker' => new WPSE67791_Walker_Category
               )); ?>
        </ul><!-- #sections -->
        <?php } ?>
```

Now the first check (is_home/is_frontpage) works just fine. So does the second (the one on "gamenews").

However, the last one ("hobbynews") doesn't work.

Each time I visit page which has that requirement (is on category/children of/has the category of "hobbynews"), it displays stuff which is *supposed to be* on gamenews. The one I want to display on hobbynews does not show up.

Why is this happening? I've been trying to re-order, tried to use nested if, etc. But it's still not working and really confusing...

---

**EDIT:**

This is my `is_category_or_sub`, located on `functions.php`:

```
function is_category_or_sub( $cat_slug = get_category_by_slug ) {
    foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) {
        if ($cat_slug || cat_is_ancestor_of($cat_slug->term_id, $cat)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try to replace your first elseif statement with `elseif ( false ) ...` and see if you ever reach your second one. You should also paste the code for your custom `is_category_or_sub` function.

Comment: When I replace it with `elseif (false)`, it reaches the second one. Both the gamenews and hobbynews now display content meant for hobbynews. Ok, I'll edit the question.

Comment: It is edited now

Comment: can you check switching the hobbynews & gamenews if conditions

Comment: @MridulAggarwal when I switch the place, what happens is the same like when I do what kovshenin told me to do. The second one's content shows up on both categories, while the first one's content does not show up.

Comment: Please try doing a `var_dump` on the `global $wp_query` object, it might give you some hints

Comment: @MridulAggarwal Erm, sorry... I'm not quite a programmer, so I'm not sure what do you mean by that... In which I'm supposed to write it?

Comment: @deathlock I meant adding `<?php global $wp_query; echo '<pre>'; var_dump($wp_query->posts); echo '</pre>';?>` just before the first if. This will show on screen the post which is being checked for the category

Comment: @MridulAggarwal Ok, I put it before the first `if`... it results in a horde of lines. But I manage to understand that the posts being displayed are indeed posts that belong under the `hobbynews` (or its child) category. So what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the function is_category_or_sub() as given on http://valendesigns.com/wordpress/is-category-or-subcategory-wp-function/

That function takes category id as the argument, not the slug. The string "gamenews" here when type-casted to an integer becomes 0 which is an ancestor for every other category. Can you try changing the function code to this-

```
// If is category or subcategory of $cat
if (!function_exists('is_category_or_sub')) {
    function is_category_or_sub($cat = 0) {
            if(is_numeric($cat)) {
                $cat_id = $cat;
            } elseif(is_string($cat)) {
                $cat = get_term_by('slug', $cat, 'category');
                $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
            } else {
                return false; // neither id nor slug
            }
            foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) {
                if ($cat_id == $cat->cat_ID || cat_is_ancestor_of($cat_id, $cat)) return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

This function now supports both id & slug

Comment: Yes, I indeed base my code on Valendesign's, however I modified it so it could read the slug. The first elseif (gamenews) works perfectly fine. The only problem lies on the second elseif (hobbynews).

Comment: I have edited my question to include my `is_category_or_sub`, please check it out :)

Comment: I feel so incredibly stupid as to WHY DIDN'T I use your function instead of persisting on mine. Once I change my `is_category_or_sub` to the one you've wrote, it works magically! Really wonderful. I still don't understand though, why is your code working and mine does not? Mostly because of my lack of programming expertise, but if an explanation is allowed I'd really be thankful.

Comment: The "if ($cat_slug" part will always return true, when $cat_slug is a non-empty string.

Comment: glad you got it working

Comment: @Otto: Oh I see, so that's where the difference! Thanks a lot! :)